# Rotate Swift Array

Tags: swift

I am trying to solve this question I found on a coding challenge website using Swift 3.

I'm sure most of you have seen it before, but in case you haven't here it is...

The idea is you take a string and rotate it x number of times. So using their example "12345" rotated 2x would be "34512"

I wrote this, but it when I print it out in Playground it just prints out the exact same string I entered.

```
func rotateSring(originalString: String, numberOfRotations: Int) -> String {

  var tempArray: [String] = []
  tempArray.append(originalString)

  let count = numberOfRotations

  for _ in 1...count {
    for letter in tempArray {

      tempArray.remove(at: 0)
      tempArray.append(letter)

    }
  }

  let newString = tempArray.joined(separator: "")

  return newString
}
```

I also tried a variation

```
func rotateSring(originalString: String, numberOfRotations: Int) -> String {

  var tempArray: [String] = []
  tempArray.append(originalString)

  let count = numberOfRotations

  for _ in 1...count {

      let test =tempArray.remove(at: 0)

      tempArray.append(test)
  }

  let newString = tempArray.joined(separator: "")

  return newString
}
```

Neither produce the desired result when I say

```
let testRun = rotateSring(originalString: "12345", numberOfRotations: 2)
```

I would like the "34512" but instead I get "12345"

If I had to guess what I am doing wrong, I think that I am just rotating the entire array from start to finish so it does move but it moves full circle.

If somebody could explain what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix it that would be great. Thank you

Comment: I think you should study about `array slices` you'll find your answer there

Comment: Also instead of using `var tempArray: [String] = []` why not use `var tempArray: [Character] = originalString.characters`

Comment: Use a compiled project and *debug* your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone through your solution and found few mistakes. The below implementation will work.

```
func rotateSring(originalString: String, numberOfRotations: Int) -> String {

    var tempArray: [Character] = Array(originalString.characters)

    let count = numberOfRotations

    for _ in 1...count {
        let letter = tempArray.removeFirst()
        tempArray.append(letter)
    }

    let newString = String(tempArray)

    return newString
}

let testRun = rotateSring(originalString: "12345", numberOfRotations: 2)
```

Now let me explain the changes:

```
  var tempArray: [String] = []
  tempArray.append(originalString)

  // to
  var tempArray: [Character] = Array(originalString.characters)
```

In Swift, `String` doesn't conform to `Sequence` type protocol and so you need to use `Character` array and so when you were trying to loop over `letters`, you were actually looping over the whole string i.e. `12345`.

```
  // tempArray = ["12345"] not ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  for letter in tempArray {
     tempArray.remove(at: 0)
     tempArray.append(letter)
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate explaining where my mistakes were and reworking my original function to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

```
func rotateSring(originalString: String, numberOfRotations: UInt) -> String {

    if numberOfRotations == 0 {
        return originalString
    }

    return rotateSring(originalString: originalString[originalString.index(after: originalString.startIndex)..<originalString.endIndex] + String(originalString[originalString.startIndex]),
                       numberOfRotations: numberOfRotations - 1)
}
```

Comment: An answer is more helpful if you explain what OP did wrong and how it is fixed instead of posting code only.

Comment: Ok thanks. @Rahul already explained OP what he's done wrong. I just posted an alternate vision of how that task could be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The native String's padding function can do that for you quite efficiently :

```
let string   = "12345"
let rotation = 2
let rotated = "".padding(toLength: string.characters.count, withPad: string, startingAt: rotation % string.characters.count)
```

if you also need to support negative rotation values, you simply need to calculate the appropriate positive offset:

```
let string   = "12345"
let rotation = -3
let offset   = ( rotation % string.characters.count + string.characters.count ) % string.characters.count
let rotated = "".padding(toLength: string.characters.count, withPad: string, startingAt: offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrongly in both tries is that you used a `[String]` with only one element in it - `originalString`. So when you remove the element at index `0`, the array becomes empty.

Here is a solution of mine:

```
func rotateSring(originalString: String, numberOfRotations: Int) -> String {
    var str = originalString
    for _ in 0..<numberOfRotations {
        let firstChar = str.characters.first! // temporarily store the first char
        var c = str.characters.dropFirst() // remove the first char from the string
        c.append(firstChar) // add the first char back to the end
        str.characters = c
    }
    return str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Rotation by using `substring(to:)` and `substring(from:)`

The accepted answer have already covered fixing your own solution; I'll pitch in with another alternative, making use of the [`substring(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1643184-substring) and [`substring(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642883-substring) methods of `String` to rotate a given string a supplied number of characters. The supplied `String` will be left-rotated (`<-` shift) for positive rotation numbers, and right-rotated for (`->` shift) for negative numbers.

```
// "left-rotate" supplied string using substring concenation
// (negative supplied rotations will be applied as "right-rotations")
func rotateString(originalString: String, numberOfRotations: Int) -> String {

    // rotation is a non-changing operation upon empty or single-character strings
    guard case let charCount = originalString.characters.count,
        charCount > 1 else { return originalString }

    // remove redundant full cycle rotation, and change rotation
    // direction (left -> right) in case the supplied rotations are negative.
    let numberOfRotations = numberOfRotations % charCount
        + (numberOfRotations < 0 ? 1 : 0) * charCount

    // use substring methods to construct the "rotated" String
    if numberOfRotations != 0 {
        let splitIndex = originalString
            .index(originalString.startIndex, offsetBy: numberOfRotations)
        return originalString.substring(from: splitIndex) +
            originalString.substring(to: splitIndex)
    }

    return originalString
}
```

Example usage:

```
let str = "1345"

// left rotations
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: 1))  // 3451
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: 2))  // 3451
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: 6))  // 3451

// right rotations
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: -2)) // 4513
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: -6)) // 5134

// no rotations (/ only full cycles)
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: 5))  // 1345
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: -5))  // 1345
print(rotateString(originalString: str, numberOfRotations: 0))  // 1345
```

---

Or, as a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func rotated(by numberOfRotations: Int) -> String {
        guard case let charCount = characters.count,
            charCount > 1 else { return self }

        let numberOfRotations = numberOfRotations % charCount
            + (numberOfRotations < 0 ? 1 : 0) * charCount

        if numberOfRotations != 0 {
            let splitIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: numberOfRotations)
            return substring(from: splitIndex) + substring(to: splitIndex)
        }

        return self
    }
}

/* example usage */
let str = "1345"

// left rotations
print(str.rotated(by: 1))  // 3451
print(str.rotated(by: 2))  // 3451
print(str.rotated(by: 6))  // 3451

// right rotations
print(str.rotated(by: -2)) // 4513
print(str.rotated(by: -6)) // 5134

// no rotations (/ only full cycles)
print(str.rotated(by: 5))  // 1345
print(str.rotated(by: -5)) // 1345
print(str.rotated(by: 0))  // 1345
```

Answer (score 0):

### code

```swift
extension String {
    mutating func rotate(by count_: Int) {
        guard count_ != 0 else { return }
        if count_ < 0 {
            let count = -count_ % self.count
            let tailRange = index(endIndex, offsetBy: -count)..<endIndex
            let tail = String(self[tailRange])
            removeSubrange(tailRange)
            self = tail + self
        } else {
            let count = count_ % self.count
            let headRange = startIndex..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: count)
            let head = String(self[headRange])
            removeSubrange(headRange)
            self = self + head
        }
    }
    
    mutating func rotated(by count: Int) -> String {
        rotate(by: count)
        return self
    }
}
```

Although it's not the most performant way, you can solve this with a recursive function as well:

```swift
    mutating func rotate(by count_: Int) {
        guard count_ >= 0 else { return rotate(by: count - (-count_ % count)) }
            let count = count_ % self.count
            let headRange = startIndex..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: count)
            let head = String(self[headRange])
            removeSubrange(headRange)
            self = self + head
    }
```

### usage

```swift
var english = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
var hangeul = "ㅁ모몸마맘뫄뫔"

english.rotate(by: 3)
print(english)                 //DEFGHIJABC
print(hangeul.rotated(by: 1))  //모몸마맘뫄뫔ㅁ
```